# Smallest $x+y$ for integer equation $n = 5x + 3y$ in closed form

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

What is the smallest value of $x + y$ that satisfies $n = 3x + 5y$, if such $(x, y)$ exists, in a closed form, where all variables are natural numbers? (Such solution does not exist for $n=1$, $n=2$, $n=4$ or $n=7$)
I am given that $\left\lfloor \frac{n + 2 (2n\ \mathrm{mod}\ 5)}{5} \right\rfloor$ is the solution.

I was able to show that $y \in \{0, 1, 2, 3, 4\}$, as $3y \equiv n\ (\mathrm{mod}\ 5)$ and $\mathrm{gcd}(3, 5) = 1$. But I couldn’t figure out how to get $x$ in closed form.

Any help or suggestions are appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Wait. is this true.  If $n=8$ then $3*1+5*1=8$ then $x+y=2$ but $[\frac {8 + (16\mod 5)}5]=[\frac 95] =1$.  Is that supposed to be the ceiling function?

Comment: @fleablood Yes, it should've been $2(2n\ \mathrm{mod}\ 5)$. I editted it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The integer solutions of $n = 5x + 3y$ are given by $x=3t-n$, $y=-5t+2n$, with $t \in \mathbb Z$.

To minimize $x+y=-2t+n$, we need to maximize $t$.

Now:

- $x\ge0\ $ iff $\ 3t \ge n$.
- $y\ge0\ $ iff $\ 2n \ge 5t$.
- $x+y\ge0\ $ iff $\ n \ge 2t$.

These gives
$
\frac{n}{3} \le t \le \frac{2n}{5} \le \frac{n}{2}
$.

Therefore, $ t \le \left\lfloor\frac{2n}{5} \right\rfloor$ and so the smallest value of $x+y$ is $-2\left\lfloor\frac{2n}{5} \right\rfloor+n$.

Answer (score 0):

So we have:

$$n=3x+5y\Rightarrow n=5x+5y-2x \Rightarrow 5(x+y)=n+2x \Rightarrow x+y=\frac {n+2x}{5}$$

$x$ and $y$ are both natural numbers. Hence their addition $x+y$ is too a natural number. So $ \frac {n+2x}{5}$ must be a natural number too. In order for that to happen must $(n+2x)\mathrm{mod} 5=0$ which only happens when $2x=kn\ \mathrm{mod}\ 5  \Rightarrow x= \frac{kn\ \mathrm{mod}\ 5}{2} $, where $k$ is a natural number that we don't know the value yet, and now $x+y = \frac {  n + ( kn\ \mathrm{mod}\ 5 ) }{5}$. But as we know x is natural number. Which means that we must be sure that $n\ \mathrm{mod}\ 5$ is divided by 2. So from here we find out that $k=2$ and $  2x=\left\lfloor 2n\ \mathrm{mod}\ 5 \right\rfloor $.

After all we have:

$x+y$ smallest value is $ \left\lfloor\frac {n+(2n\ \mathrm{mod}\ 5)}{5}\right\rfloor$, when $x= \left\lfloor \frac{2n\ \mathrm{mod}\ 5}{2} \right\rfloor$.

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow the part "which only happens when $2x = kn\ \mathrm{mod}\ 5$". I do see that $n + 2x \equiv 0\ \mathrm{mod}\ 5 \Rightarrow 2x \equiv -n\ \mathrm{mod}\ 5 \Rightarrow x \equiv \frac{-n\ \mathrm{mod} 5}{2}$, though the last $x \equiv \frac{-n\ \mathrm{mod} 5}{2}$ seems a bit ambiguous to me.

Comment: I mean that 2x must be a value that when you add it to n it produces an answer divided by 5. I put the parameter k in there cause, as you see later, it isn't enough just to have $2x=knmod5$ but we must have $2x=2nmod5$ in order for x to be an integer.